# How to get String value from the List that QueryString returns?

Tags: scala, playframework

Newbie question on Play!/Scala:
How do I get the String stored in **result**?

```
object App extends Application {
  def route = {
    case GET(Path("/feed/geocodeo")) & QueryString(qs) => Action{ request=>
      val result = QueryString(qs,"latlng").getOrElse("40.714224,-73.961452")
      val response = WS.url("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+result.toString+"&sensor=false").get()
      val body = response.value.get.body
      Ok(body).as("text/html")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if QueryString is returning List[String], so edited the original question and omitted the QueryString statement.

Comment: Where is QueryString defined? I'm trying to find the docs for it, but having no luck. Seeing your imports may help a lot, too.

Comment: import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import play.libs._

QueryString is returning Option[java.util.List[java.lang.String]]. The issue is resolved. Brian explained below and the cheat sheet on Option was helpful: http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If QueryString returns a List[String], then your code shouldn't compile.

```
scala> List("hi","bye").getOrElse("whatever")
<console>:8: error: value getOrElse is not a member of List[java.lang.String]
              List("hi","bye").getOrElse("whatever")
                               ^
```

Does your code compile?  If so, QueryString is something that has a getOrElse method, and result is the most specific superclass of String and whatever is returned by QueryString.

Usually you'd call getOrElse on an `Option[Something]`, and the object passed to getOrElse should have the same type as `Something` or else you're going to get back an object with a type that isn't going to be useful.

Comment: The code compiles, but I'm not able to extract the String value in result

Comment: Thanks Brian. Understanding the use of Option helped resolve the issue.
`code`
      var result = QueryString(qs,"latlng")
      var url : String = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
      if (result.isEmpty)
        url +="40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false"
      else
        url += result.get.get(0) + "&sensor=false"
      val response = WS.url(url).get()
`code`

Comment: A more concise way might be to: `val url = result.headOption map ( "http://whatever/"+_+"/etc") getOrElse "http://a.diferent.url"`
If result is a `List[String]`, `.headOption` returns an `Option[String]`.  Mapping over an option with a function inserts the string (if it's there) into the `_`, and returns an `Option[String]` with the resulting URL.  If the list was empty, the result will be `None`, and the `getOrElse` will provide the alternate URL.